# Merge series of differing length correctly on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Set-up**

I have a `df1`,

```
     A    B   name
0  ABC  DEF  test1
1  UVW  XYZ  test2
```

and a `df2`,

```
   C   name
0  1  test1
```

and a `df3`,

```
   C  D   name
0  1  1  test2
```

such that `df12 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name'])` gives,

```
     A    B   name  C
0  ABC  DEF  test1  1
```

and `df13 = pd.merge(df1, df3, on=['name'])` gives,

```
     A    B   name  C  D
0  UVW  XYZ  test2  1  1
```

---

**Problem**

How can I *subsequently* add first `df2` and secondly `df3` to `df1` such that I obtain a `df123` that looks like,

```
     A    B   name  C  D
0  ABC  DEF  test1  1  NaN
1  UVW  XYZ  test2  1  1
```

I need to be able to construct `df123` in a loop.

Comment: I think `df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='name'), dfs)` should working

Comment: I get a `NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined`.

Comment: use `from functools import reduce`

Comment: @jezrael I will reopen it since it is not a merge problem .

Comment: @jezrael yes this one is more like the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `combine_first` with `set_index()`

```
df1=df1.set_index('name')
df1.combine_first(df2.set_index('name')).combine_first(df3.set_index('name'))
Out[144]: 
         A    B    C    D
name                     
test1  ABC  DEF  1.0  NaN
test2  UVW  XYZ  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` and `merge`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.append(df3, sort=False),on='name')

print(df)
     A    B   name  C    D
0  ABC  DEF  test1  1  NaN
1  UVW  XYZ  test2  1  1.0
```

Comment: This gives `TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'`

Comment: @LucSpan remove `sort=False` it is latest pandas version >= 0.23.0